# Equivalence of categories preserves balancedness

Tags: category-theory

I'm sorry for the silly question I'm going to ask.

Well, if $C$ and $D$ are two equivalent categories and $C$ is balanced, is it true that also $D$ is balanced? Intuitively, it seems to be true because equivalences preserve monomorphisms, epimorphisms and isomorphisms.

If not, can you provide a counterexample? Moreover, in this case, if $C$ and $D$ are isomorphic and $C$ is balanced, then also $D$ is?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, a category equivalence preserves monomorphisms and epimorphisms, and, as any functor, also isomorphisms.

Hence, in this case $C$ is balanced if and only if $D$ is balanced.

Since isomorphism of categories is a special case of equivalence, of course it also holds for isomorphic categories.